# Is there a socket wrapper around winsock kernel (WSK, not winsock2)?

Tags: sockets, kernel, winsock, ipv6, windows-kernel

I need to upgrade a Windows Kernel Mode Driver from IPV4 to IPV4/IPV6 but the existing kernel mode socket library which uses TDI does not support IPV6.

So I would like to change the socket library to "Winsock Kernel" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571084(v=vs.85).aspx 
Note: This is not winsock2.

I started making the necessary modifications to use WSK instead of Kernsock from Storagecraft but there is a lot to consider given that this driver code runs on both windows and linux.

I am wondering if there is a kernel mode socket wrapper around WSK available, preferably with BSD or winsock2 function API signatures.  My searches do not yield anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one UDP code project which seems to provide most of what I need.

I thought I would post it here for anyone else who needs a WSK wrapper.

Project:
https://code.google.com/p/wskudp/

UDP Source:
https://code.google.com/p/wskudp/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fwskudp

TCP Source:
https://code.google.com/p/wskudp/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fwsktcp

Thanks to https://code.google.com/u/x86ddk/ for creating the project.

**NOTE**: I haven't tested this yet.